# Convert Javascript Array to JSON User Defined Key/Value Pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to take a string from a text input and convert it from an array to a JSON object.

```
let orderInputArray = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"];
let json = {}
let key,value;

orderInputArray.forEach(function(keyValue) {
  json[key] = keyValue.value;
});

let orderInputJSON = JSON.stringify(orderInputArray);
```

I need it to look like:

```
[{"key1": "value1"}, {"key2": "value2"}]
```

I'm not quite sure how to do this with the for each loop. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Why dont you use a for loop with an increment of 2 per iteration?

Comment: look for array.splice

Comment: Any reason you must specifically use a `forEach` loop vs a regular for loop?

Comment: @mr.void How can splice help in this case?

Comment: @WookieCoder i think its more handy than a old-style for-loop

Comment: @mr.void the string is spliced into an array. It seemed unnecessary to include in the code sample, though.

Comment: @bugwheels94 with splice you could pick the first two items while array.length > 0.

Comment: @WookieCoder honestly, I saw an example I was trying to use that was implementing a forEach. I think I am going to try a for loop instead though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the ideal way to create an object, but you can skip the key, create an object with the key/value using the current index (`i`), and push it to the result (`orderInputObjects`):

```js
const orderInputArray = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"];
const orderInputObjects = [];

orderInputArray.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
  if(i % 2) orderInputObjects.push({ [a[i - 1]]: v });
});

console.log(orderInputObjects);
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue was on my side. This works perfectly.

Comment: Quick question: if I wanted to use {"key1" : "value1","key2" : "value2","key3" : "value3"} instead, how would I modify the code? I also noticed " " surrounding the array brackets, how would I remove those?

Comment: This should give you an object - `if(i % 2) obj[a[i - 1]] = v;`. I'm not sure what you mean about the brackets.

Comment: I actually stringified the object later on in my code, so that was the issue. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple for loop and increment by 2 instead of 1

```
function arrayToKeyValue(array) {
  let updated = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    const key = array[i];
    const value = array[i + 1];
    updated.push({ key: value });
  }
  return updated;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` uses a call back function, therefore it is not guaranteed to finish before the `let orderInputJSON = JSON.stringify(orderInputArray);` in your code.

Try using

```
var i;

for (i =0; i < orderInputArray.length; i=i+2){
//create object here using orderInputArray[i] as key and orderInputArray[i+1] as value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` to create an array of odd and even , then use reduce function to create the array of object

```js
let orderInputArray = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"];
let vals = orderInputArray.filter(function(item, index) {
  return index % 2 === 1

});
let keys = orderInputArray.filter(function(item, index) {
  return index % 2 === 0

}).reduce(function(acc, curr, index) {
  acc.push({
    [curr]: vals[index]
  })
  return acc
}, []);
console.log(keys)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as well

```js
let orderInputArray = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"];
var l = orderInputArray.length;
var jsobj = orderInputArray.reduce(function(acc, v, i) {
    var o = {};
    if (i % 2 === 0 && i < l - 1) {
        o[v] = orderInputArray[i + 1];
        acc.push(o)
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsobj))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution with splice:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];

var json = {};
while(fruits.length > 0){
    let a = fruits.splice(0,2)
    console.log(a)
    json[a[0]] = a[1]
}

console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let orderInputArray = ["key1", "value1", "key2", "value2"];
jsonArray = [];
orderInputArray.forEach((item, i, a)=> {if(i%2 === 0) jsonArray.push({item:a[i+1]})});

console.log(jsonArray)
```